# What is the maximum number of shortest paths between any pair of vertices in a chordal graph?

Tags: graphs, combinatorics, shortest-path, discrete-mathematics

A graph $G$ is *[chordal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chordal_graph)* if it doesn't have induced cycles of length 4 or more. Chordal graphs are precisely the class of graphs that admit a *clique tree* representation. A clique tree $T$ of $G$ is a tree in which the vertices of the tree are the maximal cliques of $G$. An edge in $T$ corresponds to a *[minimal separator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chordal_graph#Minimal_separators)*. In general, $G$ can have more than one clique tree representing it. A graph is said to be *geodetic* if the shortest path between any pair of vertices is unique.

Consider a chordal graph $G$ in which every minimal separator is a singleton set. I can prove such a graph is geodetic, but this property doesn't hold once minimal separators get larger. For example, consider a graph with a minimal separator $S = \{2,3\}$ of size 2 below. It already has 2 shortest paths between the vertices 1 and 4.

[image: A chordal graph in which the minimal separator is of size 2.]

In fact, consider two adjacent vertices in a clique tree of a chordal graph. Let $S$ be the minimal separator corresponding to the edge between them. Now consider two distinct vertices $u$ and $v$ in these adjacent cliques such that $u,v \notin S$. The number of shortest paths from $u$ to $v$ is the size of the minimal separator between them. This is because, roughly speaking, it takes one step to move from any vertex in a clique to a separator, and likewise any vertex in a clique can be reached with one step from the separator.

Finally, consider an example like below. The graph has 3 maximal cliques, and the minimal separators are $\{ 4,5 \}$ and $\{ 2,3 \}$. Now the number of shortest paths from 1 to 6 is $2 \times 2 = 4$.

[image]

> Given a connected chordal graph $G$ (with no loops nor parallel edges), what is the maximum number of shortest paths there can exist between any pair of vertices? How can it be bounded (in terms of $n$ and $m$)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It can be exponential in $n/2$.  The following graph has $2^{(n/2) - 1}$ shortest paths between the endpoints:[image: Chordal graph with exponentially many shortest paths between a pair]

This graph has $2^{(14/2)-1} = 2^6 = 64$ different shortest path, each corresponding to a selection of "ups" and "downs".

Comment: Thanks! Your graph is missing labels 10 and 13. If you don't mind, I'll update the pic :-)

Comment: Thanks, @Juho.  The graph was a hack, indeed the labels aren't necessary.  Indeed, the best would be if the endpoints were labeled $s$ and $t$ and the rest was unlabeled.

Comment: BTW, did you mean $2^{(n/2)-1}$ shortest paths?

Comment: @Juho Yes, I did.  I was planning on writing exponential in $(n-2) / 2$ and when moving it into a power, things got messed up.  Thanks (again).