# Average length of s-t (simple) paths in a directed graph

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, graphs, approximation, enumeration

Given the fact that $s$-$t$ path enumeration is a #P-complete problem, could there be efficient methods that compute (or at least approximate) the average length of $s$-$t$ path without enumerating them? <strike>What if paths are allowed to revisit vertices?</strike>

Relevant results on special graphs could also be helpful.

Comment: If paths are allowed to revisit vertices, then a non-simple $s-t$ path implies that there is no average length, as the length will tend to infinity.

Comment: @Shaull, you are right. I was thinking of the hitting time of a random walk from $s$ to $t$. But the *average length* does tend to infinity without further constraints.

Comment: this seems to be very advanced, recommend migrate to cstheory

Comment: If I understand right, [this question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/10438/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-shortest-paths-between-any-pair-of-vertices-in-a-c) might be of interest to you for a special graph.

Comment: seems like this might be related to max network flow? also note for small world graphs and various other graphs with some symmetry, it will tend toward the [average path length](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average_path_length). a fairly natural algorithm might be to randomly sample shortest $s$-$t$ paths and look at the standard deviation of results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

calculating/estimating/approximating the [average path length](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average_path_length) has been studied for some random graph models including the Erdos-Renyi model and the Barabasi-Albert scale free networks, and also the Strogatz small world graphs which may be suitable as approximations for your graphs. [it would be better if you could narrow down/detail some nature/characteristics of the graphs you're studying.]

- [Computing the average path length and a label-based routing in a small-world graph — Philippe J. Giabbanelli, Dorian Mazauric, and Stephane Perennes](http://hal.inria.fr/docs/00/47/22/15/PDF/algotel.pdf)
- [Average path length in random networks — Agata Fronczak, Piotr Fronczak, Janusz A. Holyst](http://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0212230)
- [The average distance in a random graph with given expected degrees
  — Fan Chung, Linyuan Lu](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~fan/wp/aveflong.pdf)
- [AN ESTIMATION OF THE SHORTEST AND LARGEST AVERAGE PATH LENGTH IN GRAPHS OF GIVEN DENSITY — Laszlo Gulyas, Gabor Horvath, Tamas Cseri and George Kampis](http://litis.univ-lehavre.fr/~bertelle/epnacs2011/epnacs2011-proceedings/inp-gulyas4epnacs2011.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for the comment and the references. I came up with this problem when trying to model the workload of a query processing system with probabilistic graph. The graph model does have some unique properties that lead me to believe that there might be an approximation of the average length $s$-$t$ paths. As suggested in your comment, random sampling does give an approximation. Problem is that it does not give a guaranteed upper bound of the approximation, except the length of the longest $s$-$t$ path. Worse still, computing the longest $s$-$t$ path itself is a NP-complete problem.